# Excel screenshot range changing width between images

Tags: vba

I have the following code for creating images of certain areas on an Excel sheet. The widths of the columns (in each picture range) all add up to the same total column width. However there is one image which comes through as wider than all of the others and I am not sure why? Is there something in my code that I can add to keep exact measurements? Or a different way of doing this entirely?

Thanks,

James

```
Function PrintJPG(rPicRange As Range, iFileNameCounter As Integer)

'Dim iDateNumber As Integer

''' Set Range you want to export to file
    Dim rgExp As Range: Set rgExp = rPicRange
    ''' Copy range as picture onto Clipboard
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'ClearClipboard
    rgExp.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
    ''' Create an empty chart with exact size of range copied
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rgExp.Left, Top:=rgExp.Top, _
    Width:=rgExp.Width, Height:=rgExp.Height)
    .Name = "ChartVolumeMetricsDevEXPORT"
    .Activate
    End With

    ''' Paste into chart area, export to file, delete chart.
    ActiveChart.Paste

    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("ChartVolumeMetricsDevEXPORT").Border
        .Weight = 1
        .LineStyle = 0
    End With

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("ChartVolumeMetricsDevEXPORT").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("ChartVolumeMetricsDevEXPORT").Chart.Export "C:\Folder\Images\Picture" & iFileNameCounter & gSrcFileDate & gDateNumber & ".jpg"

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("ChartVolumeMetricsDevEXPORT").Delete

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Function
```

Comment: Did you verify that rPicRange.Width returns the right/expected value for the range that gets a different width?